# How to define a required element inside a CompoundElement for a FormFunction?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

For example, in the following form:

```
SystemOpen@
 CloudPublish[
  FormFunction[{
    "List" -> <|
      "Label" -> "Sample list",
      "Required" -> False,
      "Interpreter" :> 
       RepeatingElement[
        CompoundElement[
         <|
          
          "Date" -> <|
            
            "Interpreter" -> 
             Interpreter["Date", (If [MissingQ@#, False, True]) &],
            "Required" -> True
            |>,
          
          "Description" -> <|
            
            "Label" -> "Text description",
            
            "Interpreter" -> 
             Interpreter["String", (If [MissingQ@#, False, True]) &],
            "Required" -> True
            |>
          |>
         ],
        {4, {1, Infinity}}
        ]
      |>
    },
   InputForm
   ],
  AutoRemove -> True
  ]
```

I want the user to be able to submit ONLY when there is at least one valid combination of "Date" and "Description" on the repeating compound element.

I tried to define each element as "Required" with no luck, also tried to define a custom interpreter to see if it is `Missing`.